# How to change product prices in WooCommerce cart when product amount is more than one?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, price

I am a PHP noob. I'm helping my friend set up a WooCommerce shop. He sells digital products. His pricing plan is as follows:

-buy the first copy of a product for full price (10€)
-buy all other copies for a discounted price (1€)

So, when a customer adds a product to their shopping cart, the first copy is full price. The prices of any additional copies of said product are added to the cart with discounted prices.

According to the pricing plan above, if a customer has two copies of a product in their cart, the total cart price should be 11€.

I've cobbled together this code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'change_cart_price', 9999);

function change_cart_price($price_html) {
foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
    //get the quantity of each separate product in the cart
    $quantity = $cart_item['quantity'];
    
    //if the quantity of an item is higher than one,
    //decrease the for loop iterations by one
    if ($quantity > 1) {
        $iterations = $quantity -1;
            
        //change the prices of all but one copy of the product
        for ($i = 0; $i < $iterations; $i++) {
            $price = $cart_item['data']->get_price();
            $cart_item['data']->set_price(1);
        }
    }
    
}
return $price_html;
}
```

This code fires when the amount of a product in the cart is above one, but it changes the prices of all copies of the product. So, the cart total for two copies of a single product is 2€, instead of 11€.

Obviously, my "for" loop sucks. I've Googled different resources, but they tend to focus on changing the price of all the items in the cart.

I've thought about using an array that contains all the products. Maybe if I run through it and change prices according to Product ID?

Any help would be appreciated. Cheers.

**UPDATE**
I've written some code, based on 7uc1f3r's advice.
The first bit changes a product's price on the Shop page, whenever they have added more than one item of said product into their Shopping Cart. This code only applies to products the Customer has not bought previously:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html', 'change_shop_price', 9999, 2);

function change_shop_price($price_html, $product)
{

    // only on frontend
    if (is_admin()) return $price_html;

    // if customer not logged in, don't apply
    if (!wc_current_user_has_role('administrator')) return;

    if (empty(WC()->cart->get_cart())) {
        return $price_html;

    } else {

        //if customer hasn't yet bought the product
        if (!wc_customer_bought_product('', get_current_user_id(), $product->get_id())) {
  
            $cart = WC()->cart->get_cart();
            $product_id = $product->get_id();
            $product_cart_id = WC()->cart->generate_cart_id($product_id);
            $in_cart = WC()->cart->find_product_in_cart($product_cart_id);

            //check product quantity in cart
            if ($in_cart) {
                $quantity = $cart[$product_cart_id]['quantity'];
                
                if ($quantity >= 1) {
                    $orig_price = wc_get_price_to_display($product);

                    //what is the desired price for additional copies of product
                    $copy_price = 1;

                    //each additional item increases the price by one
                    $total_price = $orig_price + ($copy_price * ($quantity - 1));

                    //the price displayed on the shop page
                    $price_html = wc_price($total_price / $quantity);
                }
            }
        }
        return $price_html;
    }
}
```

So, that's the Shop Page sorted. This second code does the same on the Cart Page:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'change_cart_price', 9999);

function change_cart_price()
{

    if (is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX')) return;

    if (did_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals') >= 2) return;

    if (!wc_current_user_has_role('administrator')) return;

    if (empty(WC()->cart->get_cart())) {
        return;

    } else {

        foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item) {
            $product = $cart_item['data'];

            if (!wc_customer_bought_product('', get_current_user_id(), $product->get_id())) {
                $quantity = $cart_item['quantity'];
                            
                if ($quantity > 1) {
                    $copy_price = 1;

                    $price = $cart_item['data']->get_price();

                    $total_price = $price + ($copy_price * ($quantity - 1));

                    $individual_product_price = $total_price / $quantity;

                    $cart_item['data']->set_price($individual_product_price);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There's most likely redundant bits of code in there somewhere. I should also mention that I've gotten most of the code from this page/site:

https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-set-override-product-price-programmatically/

Thanks to 7uc1f3r for helping out. If anyone wants to suggest changes/revisions to this code, I would be happy to listen.

Comment: Although your question may seem simple at first glance, it is quite complicated. 
See this related question: [Disable Woocommerce cart line item quantity price calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46822974/11987538) - 
I therefore think that applying a general discount (negative fee) based on product quantities will be much simpler and, above all, will reduce the chance of margins of error.

Comment: The issue is in set_price, the value will be set for the product, whether this isset in a loop or not, it makes no difference. So after thinking about it, I see a kind of workaround, which could be applied relatively easily. It goes like this: price of the product is equal to 10. Price of the product, from the quantity of 2 is equal to 1. Makes a total of 11. At set_price you then add 5,5 (after a calculation, 11/2 = 5,5). The line total will now be 11. For 12, set_price = 4 (12/3), etc.. so it depends on how far you want to go into this, and on your knowledge to apply this to a certain extent

Comment: @7uc1f3r That's interesting. I'll definitely try out your suggestion. Thanks.